# Why doesn't port forwarding work correctly for me?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

First off, my router is a D-Link DIR-655, firmware v2.07. I'm trying to port forward port 25565.

My port forward settings are this:

[image: Port forwarding]

However, when I use [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) open port checker, it claims that I don't have that port open. It looks like this, without the blurred out parts:

[image: Not working]

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Added note: The way I want to use it is by my IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.154:25565). I have the software installed to do so (I'm using a minecraft server, connecting through minecraft), but I can't enter my IP in the IP address field, it says that it's out of the range of the LAN.

Comment: Do you actually have a machine at 192.168.0.100 with a listener open on port 25565, and have you verified that that machine does not have that port blocked in its firewall software?

Comment: My firewall has an exception built in for port 25565, so the firewall isn't it. I'm trying to run a program that uses 25565, it's not another machine.

Comment: Okay, so the machine that you're running the Minecraft server on...is that machine at 192.168.0.100? And was the Minecraft server running on port 25565 at the time you used the yougetsignal.com open port checker?

Comment: No, the minecraft server is my external IP (xxx.xxx.xxx.154) plus 25565 (so the full address to connect is xxx.xxx.xxx.154:25565). When I typed my external IP into the box, it gave me an error about how it was out of bounds of my LAN address

Comment: have you proved whether it's your LAN or windows firewall? you prove it by doing like nmap, from one computer to another's socket(IP:port), it's on the LAN, do it from another machine.

Comment: @chipperyman573 try to connect internally first, so not the external 154 address

Comment: @barlop If I type localhost or 127.0.0.1 into the address bar, it works. So I know it's not the program not working or something like that. Also, if I chose "open to LAN", I can connect over the LAN menu.

Comment: @chipperyman573 that would only test if you have a web server on 127.0.0.1:80  but you want to connect as you would to minecraft, on the port minecraft is on. can you do that internally like 127.0.0.1:6789 (if  minecraft is there), and i don't know if you use an address bar to connect to minecraft

Comment: Port forwarding tells your NAT gateway (router) to allow connections on certain ports of the gateway's public IP address, and to forward those connections to a certain private IP address and port on the LAN. Your screenshot made it look like you wanted to put your Minecraft server on LAN IP address 192.168.0.100, but allow external hosts to connect to it by connecting to port 25565 on your gateway's public IP address. Is that not the case?

Comment: It filled it in as 192. blah blah blah automatically, and when I type in my external IP it gives me this error: http://i.imgur.com/2qTOW.png

Comment: @chipperyman573 you're not listening.. Forget external ip for now. Try to connect from another machine on your lan, using your 192 address and minecraft port number. If -that- works, then try an online port scanner on your minecraft port.

Comment: @barlop it won't connect with my 192 address.

Comment: @chipperyman573  then it could be that the server isn't actually running on the port, or it could be that the firewall is stopping it. What windows version are you using?

Comment: @barlop windows 7, and I just checked the server.properties file, and it says it's running off that port. The server runs with no errors. But besides minecraft, why won't canyouseeme.org or other sites like that say that I have an open port?

Comment: @chipperyman573 they only see an open port if a)the server is running b)the firewall is letting it in  c)port forwarding is set up.  You have to do tests to figure out which isn't working. and i'm more familiar with xp than 7.  Open a cmd prompt and run netstat -aon | find "5677"  (where you change 5677 to your minecraft port), what comes up?

Comment: @barlop this is my firewall exception property: http://i.imgur.com/ZtVzE.png

Did I do it right? Also, I have my server run, it still says it's closed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4286/discussion-between-barlop-and-chipperyman573)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DIR-655, try disabling that Port Forwarding rule and entering the same information on the Virtual Servers page instead.

Then make sure you have your listener (Minecraft server) running on the machine you set up the port mapping for (the machine with LAN private IP address 192.168.0.100, apparently) and re-run the open port check web app you were using.

Answer (score 0):

Is the port open on your computer? It might be the router is forwarding the port but your computer isn't hosting anything on that port. What OS is your computer running and maybe we can go from there.

But make sure whatever service you are running that is listening on 25565 is actually listening otherwise it'll show the port is closed.

Comment: My OS is windows 7. I am running the tool that uses 25565.

Comment: what about windows firewall? or internet security software?

Comment: I added an exception to the firewall, and have no antivirus at the moment, I'm not installing any until I get this worked out so I know it's not responsible for it.

Comment: does it work inside your LAN, from another private IP address? That way you can at least separate the computer from the router so you know where to focus.

Comment: If I type localhost or 127.0.0.1 into the address bar, I can connect, if that answers your question

Comment: Localhost and 127.0.0.1 in address bar defaults to port 80. That doesn't mean your port 25565 is open. Do a netstat -an in command prompt and see if it shows up for UDP and TCP for the port either on localhost, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.100, or *.*. What does it show?

Answer (score 0):

The following are just some tips from my experience with results that show whether a port is open or not:

1) Use at least two different websites. The other port checking website I would recommend is http://www.canyouseeme.org/ In addition to telling you if the port is open or closed, it also usually gives you an error message.

2) Use a desktop program called PFPortChecker which you can get from here: http://portforward.com/help/portcheck.htm Though it checks if the port is open via the same external ip address as the websites do, it is more accurate. For example, in my case, the website that you are using, plus the other one I recommend, would both tell  me that port 21 is closed. I would then check the port on PFPortChecker, and it would tell me that port 21 is open. Then, when I would go to either website and check on the port, it would now show that it's open!

Part of the problem stems from checking the same port repeatedly as previous attempts are still checking or listening to the port and the connection has not been closed, so future immediate checks show them as closed.