# I'm trying to port forward my Minecraft server, so my friends could join. My modem is Huawei B593s-22

Tags: wireless-networking, port-forwarding, minecraft

I have tried everything, but I can't get it to work. Please help me!
Thanks!

I have one setup like this:

[image]

but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your public IP as seen by your router?

Comment: (1) Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/454641/why-doesnt-port-forwarding-work-correctly-for-me) help? (2) [This article](https://www.purevpn.com/port-forwarding/minecraft) gives a more complete list: TCP: 25565, UDP: 19132-19133, 25565.

Comment: @harrymc That didn't seem to help

Comment: Have you port-forwarded the UDP ports?

Comment: Like this? https://imgur.com/a/Zy42YSj